# Play framework 2 display video on the page

Tags: html, iframe, html-parsing, playframework-2.0

I have class Article :

```
@Entity
public class Article {  
@Id
public Long id;

@Constraints.Required
public String title;

@Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    public Date added;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
public String body;
```

}

There is part of my view file, where I show body of article:

```
<div class = "article_body">
       <p>@article.body</p>
</div>
```

I try to add tag  to the body and it is shown at the page like a simple text. 
Maybe I need to write kind of parser for finding tags in the text or any standart functions exist for this case?

Comment: You have to clarify better what do you need, we have totally no idea how the video from the title refers to your code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just shooting, you have HTML code in the `article.body`, which is escaped on the page ? In such case you need to unescape it:

```
<div class = "article_body">
    @Html(article.body)
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah!That's exactly what I needed!Sorry, I described common problem. The problem was I tried to insert video to the article with tag <iframe>, but it was displayed just like text.Thank you very much!